# Send email from Zimbra in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, zimbra

How to send email from Zimbra in Python. [This](http://naelshiab.com/tutorial-send-email-python/) is an example for gmail, is there any example for Zimbra?

Here is info:

Zimbra server : `10.0.0.8`

for login email: `https:\\10.0.0.8`

my test mail: `test_maas@b2mportal.gemlikgis.com`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:

```
import smtplib

 

server = smtplib.SMTP('10.0.0.8', 25)

server.starttls()

server.login("mail@example.com", "IAmAStrongPassword")

 

msg = "Help me with my math, please!"

server.sendmail("superteacher@math.com", "THE EMAIL ADDRESS TO SEND TO", msg)

server.quit()
```

Hopefully it will work out for you!